# How to scan through values / rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview

this is actually my first time asking. I have tried to search everything but i cant find the answer.

I want to scan through all of the values i have in DataGridView to prevent duplications from the first place. I'm using Access as my database. So far i can only check the selected row then compare it to the textbox. [My current form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfC8m.png)  I need to disable "Add" if the textbox value has a similar item name in all of the data

this is my code. It only affects the selected row. not all of the rows.

```
string item = dgvInventory.Rows[dgvInventory.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            if (tbItem.Text == item)
            {

                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
                lblAdd.Text = "Item name cannot be the same";
            }
            else
            {
                btnAdd.Enabled = true;
                lblAdd.Text = "Accepted";
            }
```

### Please help?

I tried to insert a `for` loop So this is my code now but it only happens on the last rows. What am i missing here? or what mistake did i make

```
for (int x = 0; x < dgvInventory.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                string item = dgvInventory.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                if (tbItem.Text == item)
                {

                    btnAdd.Enabled = false;
                    lblAdd.Text = "Item name cannot be the same";
                }
                else
                {
                    btnAdd.Enabled = true;
                    lblAdd.Text = "Accepted";
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can do a `for` loop then add the condition there. Something like this `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing this: a `for` loop,a `foreach` loop, Linq...

Comment: @P.Pat Thankyou for the suggestion. i tried `for (int x = 0; x < dgvInventory.Rows.Count; x++)` then `string item = dgvInventory.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString();`

Somehow it only works on the last row

Comment: Debug the code, and you'll see it does not work only in the last row. The problem is that you are setting `item` on each row,so finally you get the last row value. You need to check if the value is the same you arelooking for inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,using a `foreach`loop on the `Rows`collection of the `DataGridView`:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dgvInventory.Rows)
{
    if (tbItem.Text == dgvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found)
{
       btnAdd.Enabled = false;
       lblAdd.Text = "Item name cannot be the same";
}
else
{
       btnAdd.Enabled = true;
       lblAdd.Text = "Accepted";
}
```

Comment: This worked!. But i have to edit some things like the `dgvr.Cells[0].Value.toString()` But you basically solved it

Comment: Yes, i forgot the `ToString`. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Note: If this is what's you're looking for, but not complete, I can guide/complete the code

Use :

```
public void SetUpdatable()
{
    var canUpdate = VerifyAllRows(tbItem.Text);
    if (canUpdate)
    {
        btnAdd.Enabled = true;
        lblAdd.Text = "Accepted";
    }
    else
    {
       btnAdd.Enabled = false;
       lblAdd.Text = "Item name cannot be the same";
    }
}
```

Verify all rows:

```
public bool VerifyAllRows(string pValue)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInventory.Rows)
    {
        if (!VerifyRow(row,pValue))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Verify row:

```
public bool VerifyRow(DataGridViewRow pRow,string pValue)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in pRow.Cells)
    {
        string currentItem = cell.Value.ToString();
        if (currentItem == pValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is not what OP was looking for. This checks the columns in the selected row, OP wants to check a column in every row

Comment: Yes, this is the general idea - but once you have a method that tests a row, iterate it to test all of the rows - if it's what the OP's looking for, I can guide/complete the code.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion but im trying to scan through all of the rows. and check if the textbox has already the same text inside the datagridview

Comment: @OriNachum yeah. I can't find a way to test/check all of the rows. i can only manage the selected row and i have no idea how. i've been stuck for a long time

Comment: Does this make sense? you can iterate over the rows if you have access to the grid, and not just a specific row. Edit: Notice that using [0] only tests the first cell in the row. (Unless that's what you wanted)

Comment: @OriNachum this does makes sense. Thankyou for the info! I have learned so much in my first post here in stackoverflow

Comment: @Roi, you're welcomed! and welcome to the community :) Kindly mark this as answer, if it solved the issue.